# Defining a region as a data structure

Tags: analysis, algorithms

Is there a way for one to define a curve or region (such as a closed, 2-d disk) as a data structure into the computer, and make an algorithm which detects if a point is a boundary point, limit points, etc.? This seems like it cannot be normally answered by just "check neighborhood for a point" since there are infinite points; is there another way to do this?

Comment: There are many possibilities, with varying expressive strength and varying cost of doing basic operations. Which one to choose for a concrete application depends critically of which kinds of regions you need to be able to express.

Answer (score 0):

By a 2D disk, do you mean a circle? Or more like an ellipse?

Note that the region bounded by an ellipse is:
$$\dfrac{(x-h)^{2}}{r_{x}^{2}} +  \dfrac{(y-k)^{2}}{r_{y}^{2}} \leq 1$$

Where $h, k$ are the constants to define the Ellipse. So simply plug in your points to see if they are within the Ellipse's region. Note that if the left-hand side evaluates to $1$, the point is on the boundary.